# ML inequaility problem, finding M

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I have attempted the following problem, is my method and logic correct?

I am looking for a upper bound of;
$f(z)=z^2$.
My line is from $1-2i$ to $1+2i$.

Since we have no change in $x$, length is just $2+2$, hence $L=4$.

Now for $M$, I have $|x^2+y^2 |<M$ and am not sure what to do, what is $x$ and $y$ here and how do I get $M$?

Answer (score 0):

On the line from $1 - 2i$ to $1 + 2i$, $x = 1$ and $|y| \le 2$, hence $|z|^2\le 1^2 + 2^2 = 5$. That is, $|f(z)| \le 5$.

Comment: So you only consider the top half of the graph? What is M for the line -1-i to 1+i

Comment: What do you mean? I considered both the real and imaginary parts. As for the line from $-1 -i to 1 + i$, every point $z$ on it of the form $(1 - t)(-1 - i) + t(1 + i)$, $0 \le t \le 1$. Hence $$|z| \le (1 - t)|-1 - i| + t|1 + i| = (1 - t)\sqrt{2} + t\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{2}$$ for all $z$ on that line. So you can choose $M = 2$ in this case.

Comment: I think i understand, thank you kobe